# The terminating null character is not at the end of a string?

Tags: c++

I 've read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen)

> Defined in header 
> std::size_t strlen( const char* str );
> Returns the length of the given byte string, that is, the number of characters in a character array whose first element is pointed to by str up to and not including the first null character. The behavior is undefined if there is no null character in the character array pointed to by str.

What does "the first null character" here mean? Meaning "the null charater" at the beginning of the string? I've thought that it should be at the end of the string to mark its top instead?

Comment: The pointer will point somewhere in memory, the first byte on or after that address is taken to be the end of the string. The undefined behavior means that if you have allocated memory (say 10 bytes) and don't have a '\0' in there your code will start accessing memory it has no control over (and you will get garbage values back or the code will crash, or your code even may seem to work) Also know that in C++ using std::string (or std::string_view) is recommended for representing text.

Comment: A simple way to split C strings on line breaks, commas or whatever is to replace each separator with a null character. That's how a larger string can end up with multiple null characters. `strlen` will give you the first one even if more come after.

Comment: "First" means the first one `strlen` finds when searching for it from `str` and onwards. It does not mean that the first character should be the null character. (For instance, if your character array is `{'a', 0, 'b', 0}`, the `strlen` length is 1, not 3.)

Comment: I got it know, thank you so much everybody

Comment: "*What does "the first null character" here mean?*" It *literally* means that *the first null character*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote talks about a character array. A character array can contain the `\0` character at any position.

A null-terminated string is terminated by a `\0` after its last character.

For example both of this

```
const char x[6] = "123\0\0";  // another terminating \0 is added automatically
const char y[6] = {'1','2','3','\0','\0','\0'};
```

Define a character array with 6 characters containing a string of length 3. To determine the length of the string you need to look for the **first** null character in the character array.

Comment: It's clear now. thanks for your help!